# Laravel Migration - table not getting created

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-4

I'm trying to learn Laravel. I'm following the Quickstart documentation but have gotten into a problem with Migrations. I'm at this step: http://laravel.com/docs/quick#creating-a-migration

When I run the command `php artisan migrate`, the command line displays the following:

```
c:\wamp\www\laravel>php artisan migrate
Migration table created successfully.
Migrated: 2013_09_21_040037_create_users_table
```

In the database, I see a `migrations` table created with 1 record. However, I do not see a `users` table. So, I can't continue on to the ORM portion of the tutorial.

Any ideas what I might be doing wrong? Why isn't the `users` table getting created?

**EDIT 1 (original migration file):**

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateUsersTable extends Migration {

    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
            Schema::create('users', function($table)
            {
                $table->increments('id');
                $table->string('email')->unique();
                $table->string('name');
                $table->timestamps();
            });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
            Schema::drop('users');
    }

}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The updated Laravel should use `Blueprint` for database schema creation.
So try to change your user migration file content like this,

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;

class CreateUsersTable extends Migration {

    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('users', function(Blueprint $table) {
            $table->integer('id', true);
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('username')->unique();
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->string('password');
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->softDeletes();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::drop('users');
    }

}
```

Then run,

```
  php artisan migrate:rollback
```

and then migrate again.

Read the `API` documentation here http://laravel.com/api/class-Illuminate.Database.Schema.Blueprint.html

Comment: I couldn't rollback since "users" table cannot be dropped if it was never created in the first place. I reset the database manually instead. Your code worked. Why did it? I was following the tutorial step by step.

Comment: I think, in first time you are not written the code for table creation or drop in up and down functions. Is it working now?

Comment: I did not write the original code. I was just following the steps in the tutorial. I have updated my question and posted the original migration file. Why didn't that work? Why does your code work?

Comment: Updated laravel should use `Blueprint` for migration schema creation. Check updated answer.

Comment: Sadly this API documentations does not (in a clear fashion, anyway) why it is needed or what is happening.  For instance:  why doesn't the generated migration file include that line automatically?

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem, after searching at Laravel documentation ([link to documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/migrations#roll-back-migrate-using-a-single-command)), i found an artisan command that resolve it :

```
php artisan migrate:refresh
```

The migrate:refresh command will roll back all of your migrations and then execute the migrate command. This command effectively re-creates your entire database